# is c or c++ necessary for game programming?

Tags: game-development

Do you need to learn c or c++ for game programming? I am very good with java. Is it true that most game engines are in c or c++.should i learn c or c++ or start making games in java.Can you suggest some books to start with

Comment: Minecraft is made entirely in Java.  :-)

Comment: Why was this down voted?  Seriously, it's a reasonable question with a defined answer.

Comment: Hi chintans, I'm sorry this was migrated here unnecessarily, but you've asked about a bunch of different things that makes your question way too broad a scope to be answered in a reasonable manner. If there's something *specific* about game development you'd like to know, I'd check out our sister-site, [Game Development.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5):

Many game engines are, indeed, in C or C++, particularly the first-person-shooter types. This is because that style of game typically needs to squeeze the maximum possible performance out of the graphics hardware.

Outside of that requirement, you can pretty much use whatever language you feel like. [Puzzle Pirates](http://www.puzzlepirates.com) is 100% pure Java, and [Frozen Bubble](http://www.frozen-bubble.org/) is written in Perl.

So, to answer your question, no you do not **need** to learn C or C++. It will be helpful if you want to take full advantage of graphics hardware but not all games need that.

Comment: many games, esp silverlight games, are in C#, and lets not forget flash, oh, and iOS (iPhone,iPad,etc) games are in objective-c and the list goes on and on

Comment: Pygame is a popular framework for python games, Lua pops up all over the place.